# Echo кавычки

Tags: php, echo

Здравствуйте, столкнулась с вот такой вот проблемой. Нужно вывести командой echo код который содержит много двойных и одинарных кавычек. Как это можно сделать не прибегая к экранированию каждой кавычки в отдельности ?Заранее спасибо

Comment: Рекомендую почитать официальную документацию:  
http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.string.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот так:

```
<?php
$str = <<<EOF
<p>Hello</p>
"Mr. Smith". You're the best.
EOF;
echo $str;
?>
```

Comment: Кстати, на sh практически так же.

    str=`cat <<EOF
    xaxa 'ox "ax
    xoxox "ax" 'ox'''
    EOF`
    echo $str

Только `<<` вместо `<<<`

    avp@avp-ubu1:~$ echo $str
    xaxa 'ox "ax xoxox "ax" 'ox'''
    avp@avp-ubu1:~$

Comment: Да и на `perl` аналогично

    print <<EOF;
    All constructions
    are similar
    <p>Hello!</p>
    <form action="/cgi-bin/gd.cgi" method="post">
    ...
    </form>
    EOF

Comment: Т.е. концепция (и даже синтаксис) встроенного документа, появившаяся лет 40 назад оказалась весьма удачной.

Comment: Мне кажется, что тут дело скорее в том, что синтаксис PHP в основном содран с Perl.

Comment: @RainRaus не содран а унаследован, а синтаксис perl видимо слегка наследует синтаксис shell который слегка наследует синтаксис C (интересно было бы посмотреть на альтернативную вселенную, где эта ветка наследования пошла от Lisp а не от C)